# Call public method from jQuery plugin constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry if this question is stupid but I cannot get it..I have searched for it on internet but I have nothing found... So that's what I want to achieve:
call method `removeAllEvents` and this one `addEvents: function(events_array);`

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/n2gkm4d9/

`$("#my-calendar").data('zabuto_calendar').removeAllEvents;` -does not work

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a method you should put brackets after it to call it: `$("#my-calendar").data('zabuto_calendar').removeAllEvents();`

Answer (score 0):

Answer as the below:

```
$('#my-calendar').zabuto_calendar('removeAllEvents');
```